# ram for windows phone app

Tags: windows-phone-7

As per MS, systems requirement for windows phone sdk is 3gb RAM,
[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402530%28v=vs.92%29#BKMK_SysReqs.)

Is this a strict requirement, my laptop has only 2gb ?

Comment: Just try it.  I suspect this is more of a recommendation, as with less than 3 GB the performance will be suboptimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been making Windows Phone apps with an old laptop. First the laptop had 1gb of RAM, and the emulator wouldn't even start (but I could deploy directly to the device). I upgraded to 2gb and now it works fine. So no, it's not a strict requirement.

Answer (score 1):

ram requirement is mostly for visual studio itself because compiling siverlight(for wp) is somehow heavy and lack of ram will cause system hangs .

Answer (score 0):

The ram requirements are for Visual Studio. But you should be able to run it with 2GB of ram, it would just be slower and might run into out of memory exceptions.

The physical Window phone 7 either have 256MB ram or 512MB of ram. And are dependent on what phone model you get.

Random note, here is a link to what the specifications of a windows phone 7 must have: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637514%28v=VS.92%29.aspx

Your link is for was a computer "requires" for developing a windows phone 7 app.

Answer (score 0):

3G is required to run both Visual Studio and the phone emulator at the same time in order to interactively debug a phone app.

If you have a physical phone on which to run the application then you only need 2G of RAM on the development workstation.

I did quite a lot of work with 2G and a real phone. Just for laughs I tried using the emulator and I found that this also works in 2G but it's very slow due to lots of swapping.